# How to set default flags for Git commands?

Tags: git

As an example, I prefer viewing my Git branches using the flag `--sort=committerdate`. Is there a way to edit my `.gitconfig` to automatically use that flag?

Is there a general way to pass flags to commands by default?

Comment: Yes, I looked at that, but the question and answers deal with a more specific question.

Comment: @merlin2011's recommendation is actually a good duplicate; I'll close (there's nothing *wrong* with duplicates!).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a general way to pass flags to commands by default?

No.  Or rather, both no and yes, but it's not what you think, and `--sort` for `git branch` is not available this way.

There are two ways to do this, one general-purpose and one rather ad hoc.  The general purpose method is to use *aliases*, which can be either *shell* aliases (the precise syntax for these depends on your shell) or *Git* aliases (which are defined by Git and hence more predictable here).  For instance, you can make an alias `br` for `branch --sort=committerdate`:

```
$ git config alias.br "branch --sort=committerdate"
```

after which `git br` runs `git branch --sort=committerdate`.

The ad hoc method is *per Git command* and requires consulting both the documentation for that particular command—e.g., [the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for `git log`—and [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  Here you will find that, for instance, the `log.decorate` setting controls whether `--decorate` is the default, and the `color.branch` (not `branch.color`) setting controls whether `git branch` output is colored by default.  The "default default" for some of these defaults is often controlled by yet another setting, so that branch coloring is determined by the first of:

- the command line `--color` or `--no-color` option if specified, or
- the `color.branch` setting if specified, or
- the `color.ui` setting if specified, or
- whether output is going to a "tty device" (as determined by the C library `isatty(1)` function).

As it happens, there is no `--sort=<key>` control knob, so you are left with aliases as the only option here.  Well, that is, unless you add a `branch.sort` or `sort.branch` setting knob, and convince the Git folks to adopt it! :-)